# In (python) plotly how to start (0,0) after some padding as below

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, scatter-plot

How can we have (0,0) as below in plotly (python) in scatterplot using go.Scattergl().
How to have some padding before (0,0)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that the lower bound of the range of both axes is 0.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))

fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[0,4])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[0,4])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Or else some negative value for the lower bound, if the padding should come before (0, 0).